# how to get the state param in the GET to Auth Callback URI in Bigcommerce

Tags: bigcommerce

I have a platform where I am trying to create a connection with BC with oAuth authentication.

For this I have created an app on the developer portal and registered it using the partnerId to get the client id and client secret.

Then I make a req to BC for installing the app onto the store passing the store URL, auth callback url, state (connectionId), client id of the app published and the scope that the connection is requesting for. With this request I get to the BC login for the store and then once I am logged in, clicking on install will trigger the GET request to the auth callback url(same callback url being passed in the req and provided at the time of app registration) containing the code, scope and the context.

But I have a requirement wherein I need the state parameter that I have sent in the req for app installation to be returned back along with the three parameters that are being sent in the GET request.

If anyone have come across similar requirement and solved it with some method, please do help out and I would appreciate if BC takes up this request and add the state param along with the existing three parameters as most of the platform supporting oauth has the state params included nowadays.

Comment: do you mean the state/province or state in another context?

Comment: In this context, I mean state by one more property supported in the request param of GET req for oauth callback.

Answer (score 1):

There is no support for the state parameter. 
If this is a security concern, know that the oAuth exchange occurs after a user is already authenticated to the Bigcommerce account. Therefore, Bigcommerce has an association between the authorization code and the store it belongs to. So, if you attempt to perform a CSRF with the original authorization token against another store, it *should* actually be prevented by Bigcommerce.

oAuth CSRF Explained: 
https://security.stackexchange.com/a/57886/55072

Hope this helps,